# My pagination isn't working properly. Help!

Tags: php, pagination

```
<?php
// Code not directly relevant omitted (including lots of vars)

//Create pagination links
$first = "First";
$prev  = "Prev";
$next  = "Next";
$last  = "Last";
if($current_page>1)
{
    $prevPage = $current_page - 1;
    $first = "<a href=\"test.php?page=1\">First</a>";
    $prev  = "<a href=\"test.php?page={$prevPage}\">Prev</a>";
}
if($current_page<$total_pages)
{
    $nextPage = $current_page + 1;
    $next = "<a href=\"test.php?page={$nextPage}\">Next</a>";
    $last = "<a href=\"test.php?page={$total_pages}\">Last</a>";
}

?>
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
<h2>Here are the records for page <?php echo $current_page; ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $slots; ?>
  </ul>
Page <?php echo $current_page; ?> of <?php echo $total_pages; ?>
<br />
<?php echo "{$first} | {$prev} | {$next} | {$last}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT/UPDATE:
I just realized I had a file called test.php a while back. I deleted it but I guess it's still in my site somehow... Nevertheless, I changed the word test with works. Now when I click next, it brings me to mydomain.com/works.php?page=2. But it shows a 404 error :/

Can somebody please tell me where I screwed up? Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of deleting all the code that wasn't relevant to the pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code certainly looks good; are you sure the problem is in the *links* being generated? Maybe you are being redirected from the "correct" page for some other reason?

Comment: Thanks for deleting the irrelevant code and I just realized I had a file called test.php a while back. I deleted it but I guess it's still in my site somehow... Nevertheless, I changed the word test with works. Now when I click next, it brings me to mydomain.com/works.php?page=2. But it shows a 404 error :/

Comment: @user657847: Well, that means there's no `works.php` (which if I understand correctly is a name you just made up). The pagination works fine.

Comment: So should I upload a blankfile named works.php or something? I'm not sure how pagination works now... I thought it was supposed to automatically generate a page.

Comment: @user657847: You already have the code for paging. You just need to use the name of the original script (the one whose code you posted), instead of `test.php` or `works.php` or whatever else.